# Computing face normal in C++

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to compute normals of each face.

```
void myFace::computeNormal()
{
    myHalfedge* e1 = adjacent_halfedge;
    myHalfedge* e2 = e1->prev;
    myVertex* v1 = e1->source;
    myVertex* v2 = e2->source;
    myVertex* v3 = (e1->next)->source;
    myPoint3D* p1 = v1->point;
    myPoint3D* p2 = v2->point;
    myPoint3D* p3 = v3->point;
    myVector3D vect1 = *p3-*p1;
    myVector3D vect2 = *p2-*p1;

    normal = &vect1.crossproduct(vect2);
}

void myMesh::computeNormals()
{
    myFace* f = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        f = faces[i];
        f->computeNormal();
    }
}
```

But when `f->computeNormal();` is called, all previous values are replaced by the last computed value. Can anyone give me an advice what should be wrong?

**EDIT (Added crossproduct)**

```
void myVector3D::crossproduct(myVector3D & v1, myVector3D & v2)
{
    dX = v1.dY * v2.dZ - v1.dZ * v2.dY;
    dY = v1.dZ * v2.dX - v1.dX * v2.dZ;
    dZ = v1.dX * v2.dY - v1.dY * v2.dX;
}

myVector3D myVector3D::crossproduct(myVector3D & v1)
{
    myVector3D result;
    result.crossproduct(*this, v1);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How is crossproduct() defined? And member normal? The call looks suspicious.

Comment: Normal is defined as `myVector3D *normal;`

Comment: `normal = &vect1.crossproduct(vect2);` takes the address *of a temporary* - the returned `myVector3D` must be saved somewhere by value.  When the stack pops, the `normal` pointer's invalidated, and the next call to `crossproduct` creates the next product in the same place in the stack, so it's seen by the old invalidated pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit may be at "normal = &vect1.crossproduct(vect2)". The value of the function call "crossproduct" is only temporary inside the function "computeNormal". After exiting the function, this variable becomes invalid. So the pointer "normal" to it points to a garbage value. You may use "myVector3D normal" instead of "myVector3D *normal".

Comment: When I changed `myVector3D *normal;` to `myVector3D normal;`, I have same problem.

Comment: You changed `normal = vect1.crossproduct(vect2);` too right?